# Java JNA Native Library Call NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, classnotfoundexception, jna

I want to put a file into the recycle bin in Windows using Java. So that the user is able to restore it.

Therefore I use the library [JNA from Github](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) (jna-platform-4.2.2.jar) which accesses native Windows functions.

My Code:

```
public static boolean moveToTrashBin(File file){

    FileUtils fileUtils = FileUtils.getInstance();

    if(fileUtils.hasTrash()){   // returns true
        try{
            fileUtils.moveToTrash(new File[]{file});   // throws Exception
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

There are no compile time errors but when I try to run it, the line *fileUtils.moveToTrash(..)* throws the following NoClassDefFoundError and a ClassNotFoundExeption:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary**
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32FileUtils.moveToTrash(W32FileUtils.java:28)
>       at DropboxFix.Gui.Tools.moveToTrashBin(Tools.java:21)
>       at DropboxFix.Gui.Gui.btnDeleteFoundOnClick(Gui.java:208)
>       at DropboxFix.Gui.Gui.access$1600(Gui.java:34)
>       at DropboxFix.Gui.Gui$6.actionPerformed(Gui.java:357)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary**
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 66 more

I use IntelliJ as IDE and added the library under "Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add".

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's actually a [```NoClassDefFoundError```](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: @JornVernee Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error, just had to add the second library **jna-4.2.2.jar** from the website to my project..

I works now!